# gfortran not found in Software Center in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center

My friend using an older version of ubuntu has gfortran in the Ubuntu Software Center. I think he did not need to download anything. It was already there. He just installed it. But in my case, when I tried searching for it my own Ubuntu Software Center, I couldn't find it. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Is it really not available to the new version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and have problem like you and need gfortran that is emergency. How did you solve your problem. I did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GFortran appears in the Software Centre on my system, also 12.04.

You can skip the Software Centre, and install the compiler from the Terminal: launch the terminal, then type `sudo apt-get install gfortran`.

If the terminal gives you an error when you do this, please give us the error message.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I'm new to Ubuntu and I didn't know that the Synaptic Package Manager exists. When I found out about it, I tried it and it worked well. Anyway, thanks again for answering! I'm sure I could use some help from you again in the future. :)